# How do I interpret the results of an ARIMAX function from the PyFlux library?

Tags: python, output, augmented-reality, arima

I'm conducting an ARIMAX model of my data.

The code is:

```
model = pf.ARIMAX(data = meg_crude_merge_drop[:-12], formula='MEG~CrudeOil+1', ar=4, ma=3, integ = 2,family=pf.Normal())
```

...and the output from this code:

```
x = model.fit("MLE")
x.summary()
```

...is here:

```
Normal ARIMAX(4,2,3)                                                                                      
======================================================= ==================================================
Dependent Variable: Differenced Differenced MEG         Method: MLE                                       
Start Date: 2012-02-06 00:00:00                         Log Likelihood: -1750.1127                        
End Date: 2019-08-26 00:00:00                           AIC: 3520.2253                                    
Number of observations: 375                             BIC: 3559.4946                                    
==========================================================================================================
Latent Variable                          Estimate   Std Error  z        P>|z|    95% C.I.                 
======================================== ========== ========== ======== ======== =========================
AR(1)                                    -0.3586    0.6448     -0.5562  0.578    (-1.6224 | 0.9051)       
AR(2)                                    -0.1548    0.3045     -0.5086  0.611    (-0.7516 | 0.4419)       
AR(3)                                    0.0519     0.1271     0.4079   0.6834   (-0.1973 | 0.301)        
AR(4)                                    -0.0457    0.0632     -0.7232  0.4695   (-0.1696 | 0.0782)       
MA(1)                                    -0.4682    0.6337     -0.7389  0.46     (-1.7102 | 0.7738)       
MA(2)                                    -0.2916    0.8        -0.3645  0.7155   (-1.8597 | 1.2764)       
MA(3)                                    -0.2077    0.2552     -0.8141  0.4156   (-0.7079 | 0.2924)       
Beta 1                                   0.004      0.2216     0.0178   0.9858   (-0.4304 | 0.4384)       
Beta CrudeOil                            -0.0009    0.0036     -0.245   0.8065   (-0.008 | 0.0062)        
Normal Scale                             26.0627                                                          
==========================================================================================================
```

Does anyone know how to interpret the results?